# Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'OPT_CLIENT_MODE' in

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elasticache

Currently the connection from my ec2- amazon ami instance to elasticache does not work

I attempt to connect and fail with

```
$server_endpoint = "lolololo.olol.olol.cache.amazonaws.com";
$server_port = 11211;
$dynamic_client = new Memcached();
$dynamic_client->setOption(Memcached::OPT_CLIENT_MODE, Memcached::DYNAMIC_CLIENT_MODE); 
// it fails on previous line
// Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'OPT_CLIENT_MODE' in
$dynamic_client->addServer($server_endpoint, $server_port);
$dynamic_client->set('key', 'value', 60);
```

Steps i took
sudo yum install gcc-c++ php php-pear

sudo pecl install myplaceontheweb.com/assets/AmazonElastiCacheClusterClient-1.0.1-PHP53-64bit.tgz

sudo yum install php-devel

from root:
add

```
extension=memcached.so
extension=amazon-elasticache-cluster-client.so
```

to /etc/php.d/memcached.ini

php info says memcached is an installed part of php, i have rebooted the server after doing all of this.

```
sudo find . -type f -name 'amazon*.so'
```

yeilds ./usr/lib64/php/modules/amazon-elasticache-cluster-client.so 
and it doesn't work by direct linking as an extension either

Is there anything obvious i am doing wrong? can anyone suggest a fix?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I did this right, but I was having similar problems and finally got it working.

I was trying to install ElastiCache Cluster Client for PHP on Ubuntu 14.04 with Apache, but kept getting the "Memcached not found" error.

First, I followed the directions here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PHPAutoDiscoverySetup.html

with two changes

A.  I downloaded the tookit from

```
http://elasticache-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/ClusterClient/PHP-5.5/latest-64bit
```

B.  In addition to adding a memcache.ini file to /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/, I also added one to /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/

```
echo "extension=/full/path/to/amazon-elasticache-cluster-client.so" | sudo tee /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/memcached.ini
```

That's it.

The only other gotchas are make sure you don't have php5-memcached already installed, and also make sure you're downloading the correct version of the Cluster Client tools for your system.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `amazon-elasticache-cluster-client.so` is suppose to replace `memcached.so`. You should remove `extension=memcached.so` and restart php.

Comment: Is there any sign that the amazon client is not loading? What do you get with `php -i` or `php_info()`?

Comment: Nothing in relation to memcache. no.

Comment: For whatever reason the module is not loading. You do still have just this line in your memcached.ini? `extension=amazon-elasticache-cluster-client.so`

Comment: what version of php are you running? i'm running 5.5.7 on Ubuntu, and am running into the exact same problems.